# How to write a void method to stop the program for 1 seconds using Timer when called?

Tags: java, timer, void

The version of Java is 8u60.

I want to write a void method which could pause the program for 1 seconds but there are always exceptions.

```
public void OnePause(){
    Timer timerOne = new Timer();
    timerOne.schedule(timerOneTask(), (long)1000);}

private TimerTask timerOneTask() {
        return null;
        }
}
```

I do not want to use Thread.Sleep(); because it pauses the sum of all time when called multiple times instead of pause separately.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does "write a void" mean?  Also, you can't schedule `null` as a task like that.  What do you expect to happen when the `Timer` tries to start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code is broken. Besides trying to send `null` into `Timer.schedule(...)`, your statement `timerOne.schedule(timerOneTask(), (long)1000);}` is going to call `timerOneTask()` every 1000 milliseconds, but that does not pause the program. You must sleep the thread:

```
private TimerTask timerOneTask(int sleepTime) {
  return new DoNothingTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // awoken prematurely, handle this
      }
  }
}
```

Unless you need to schedule the "pauses" on some interval, there's no use in introducing the `Timer` API into the mix; if not, you can get simply use what's in that *try...finally* block.